# What is the best way to refresh some script function every XX minutes?

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I am working on football odds website for first time.

I am getting **xml data** from an online **xml feeder**, **parsing** xml data using PHP and send that data to mysql **database**, from another php file i get that **data** and **print** it on html **document**.

Xml feeder has **time limits** for each function, for example:
time limit for League is 3600s,
time limit for Live Fixture is 25s etc..

I send data using just one file called as sendxmldata.php, there is functions like: 
**SendLeaguesToDb**(), **SendFixturesToDb**() etc..

And now i want to run these functions every XX-XXXX seconds, so each function has different time limit.

How i can to run that functions every XX seconds, i need to run it and when users are not on website?

What is the best way to do this?

Using something like Cron Job or how? If is answer **yes**, use something like **Cron**, is there way to run an function from file for 25s, and another from same file for 3600s? Or i need for every function or time_limit create new php file to run? There is very much functions.

Thanks.

Comment: Create 2 Crons pointing to same file

Comment: How will Cron know what function to run? I can to put all functions to constructor, but it will slow down my website if i every 25s searching for all xml data or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two cronjobspointing to the same file as @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com pointed out. 
You can pass an argument to choose witch function to call:

```
1 * * * * /path_to_php/cronjob.php variable1=test variable2=test variable3=test
```

You would then use parse_str() to set and access the paramaters:

```
<?php parse_str($argv[n]); ?>
```

to use timeout as an parameter:

```
    1 * * * * /path_to_php/cronjob.php timeout=30
```

and to read it:

```
<?php $timeout = parse_str($argv[0]); ?>
```

Comment: Can i call file from php like this 
file.php?timeout=3600
file.php?timeout=30

and then in file.php get timeout and execute function?

Comment: sorry for the delay. editing my answer now. check it out